Error creating bean with name 'sqsMessageListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource
While running the application I'm getting this exception: Error creating bean with name 'sqsMessageListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource
After upgrading spring aws dependency, I made code change for my SQSConfig class. While running the application I got below exception. I'm unable to find the solution for this. Below is the exception that I got.
message":"Application run failed","context":"default","exception":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqsMessageListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/equifax/idmonitoring/config/SQSConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.awspring.cloud.sqs.config.SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory]: Factory method 'sqsMessageListenerContainerFactory' threw exception with message: org/springframework/retry/backoff/BackOffPolicyBuilder\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)

This is my SQSConfig.java:
@Configuration
@Profile({ "!mock & !test & !local" })
@Slf4j
public class SQSConfig {

@Value("${AWS_REGION}")
private String region;

@Value("${SQS_ENDPOINT}")
private String endpoint;

@Value("${aws.sqs.threadsPool.number}")
private Integer threadsPoolNumber;

@Bean(name = "sqsTemplate")
public SqsTemplate sqsTemplate(SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient){
    SqsTemplate sqsTemplate = SqsTemplate.builder().sqsAsyncClient(sqsAsyncClient).build();
    return sqsTemplate;
}

@Bean(name = "sqsAsyncClient")
public SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient(){
    SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient = null;
    try {
        
        log.info("Connecting to AWS SQS Region:{} and endpoint:{}", region, endpoint);
        sqsAsyncClient = (SqsAsyncClient) SqsAsyncClient.builder()
            .asyncConfiguration(option ->   
option.advancedOption(SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR,
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsPoolNumber)))
            .endpointOverride(URI.create(endpoint))
            .region(Region.of(region)).build();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        log.error("Error", ex);
    }
    return sqsAsyncClient;
}

@Bean
public SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory sqsMessageListenerContainerFactory(SqsAsyncClient  
sqsAsyncClient){
    return SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory.builder()
        .configure( options -> options.maxMessagesPerPoll(10))
            .sqsAsyncClient(sqsAsyncClient).build();
}
}

These are the maven dependecies:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-sns</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


Could you, please, modify stack trace in your question to make it readable?

Hi, I did modified and here my question is why this BeanCreationException was occuring at sqsMessageListenerContainerFactory in SQSConfig class

No, does not look like modification is in. That stack trace is still one ugly line. We just cannot read it to determine what exactly is an exception.
